# Sum of $k$ consecutive integers

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to prove or disprove:

Characterize $k \in\Bbb N$ that makes the following statement true: “$a$ is
divisible by $k$ if and only if $a$ can be written as a sum of $k$ consecutive integers”.

I tried the converse:

> **Proof.** If $k\mid a$ and $k=2q+1$, $q \in\Bbb Z $, then $a=c(2q+1)$ for $c \in\Bbb Z$.
>
> Notice: $$\begin{align*}ck &= (c - q) + \big(c - (q-1)\big) + \ldots+ (c -1) + c\\&+\, (c +1) +\ldots+ \big(c + (q-1)\big) + (c + q)\;,\end{align*}$$ so $ck$ is the sum of the $2q+1$ consecutive integers.
>
> Hence $a$ is expressable as a sum of $k$ consecutive integers

Is this okay? Other methods?

Comment: For the first part where you say $k|a \implies k=2q+1...$ is wrong. It should be $kq=a$ for some $q\in\mathbb{Z}$. And maybe have two cases one for when $k$ is odd and then when $k$ is even.

Comment: I guess you meant "I tried the forward direction."

Answer (score 2):

Since the statement you are trying to prove contains "if and only if", you also need to prove

"if $a$ can be written as the sum of $k$ consecutive integers, $a$ is divisible by $k$."

Also, I'm not sure if it's just me being tired, but I'm not following your 'Notice:' line of reasoning.

Comment: The reasoning is correct; the OP omitted a lot of parentheses that would have made it much clearer. I’ve taken the liberty of inserting them.

Answer (score 0):

You were asked to find a characterization of those positive integers $k$ that have a certain property; this means that you’re to find and prove a statement of the form

> a positive integer $k$ has *the specified property* if and only if $k$ is *something*.

What you’ve proved is that $k$ has the desired property if $k$ is odd; to complete the characterization you must show that if $k$ is even, it does **not** have the specified property. That means that you must show that if $k$ is an even positive integer, then there is some integer $a$ such that either

- $k\mid a$, but $a$ cannot be written as the sum of $k$ consecutive integers, or
- $k\nmid a$, but $a$ can be written as the sum of $k$ consecutive integers.

HINT: What if $a=k$?